# Order subtotals incorrect sum function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having some problems with my SQL scripts. I am trying to make a script that will allow me to calculate a sum of sales for each order, "Order Subtotal".
I am using MS SQL Server Management Studio and an old Northwind database, somehow, my script doesn't work, I am not sure where the problem might be. The program underlines some parts as incorrect column name, or wrong syntax.

```
SELECT [OrderID], 
       (SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity * (1 - Discount)), 2) as Subtotal
from [dbo].[Order Details]
group by OrderID
order by OrderID;
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum accepts only one parameter, so better format after fetching query

```
SELECT [OrderID], 
   CAST(SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity * (1 - Discount)) as NUMERIC) as Subtotal
FROM[dbo].[Order Details]
GROUP BY OrderID
ORDER BY OrderID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I used different script

```
 SELECT "Order Details".OrderID, 
Sum(CONVERT(money,("Order Details".UnitPrice*Quantity*(1-Discount)/100))*100) AS Subtotal
FROM "Order Details"
GROUP BY "Order Details".OrderID
```